# Java program crashing when attempting to show a menu and retrieve input from user (NoSuchElementException)

Tags: java, debugging, nosuchelementexception

So I have a program that takes orders for vehicle purchases (meant to learn the basics of java. Right now this iteration of the assignment is focusing on inheritance). Hierarchy: Orders.java (Main program), Vehicle.java (parent class), Boat.java/Car.java/Truck.java(child classes).

I was showing my menus manually in the main program before but tried to delegate that responsibility to my Vehicle class so it would be more generic and each child could pass in a Question Prompt and Array of Choices to the showMenu function. So nothing was being done manually anymore.

Here's what happened when it was done manually (worked fine):

```
System.out.println("What type of Car is this?");
System.out.println("\t1. Sedan");
System.out.println("\t2. Coupe");
System.out.println("\t3. Wagon");
System.out.print("Choice: ");               
while (!sc.hasNext("[123]")) {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(""); 
    System.out.println("That's not an option! Please try again.");
    System.out.println("What type of Car is this?");
    System.out.println("\t1. Sedan");
    System.out.println("\t2. Coupe");
    System.out.println("\t3. Wagon");
    System.out.print("Choice: ");   
    sc.next();
}
choice = sc.next();
if(choice.equals("1")){
    car.setCarType("Sedan");
} else if (choice.equals("2")){
    car.setCarType("Coupe");
} else if (choice.equals("3")){
    car.setCarType("Wagon");
} else{
    car.setCarType("unknown");
}
```

Here's how it works now (crashes before stopping to let the user give input):

```
public int showMenu(String prompt, String[] choices){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(prompt);
    String choiceIdentifiers = "";
    int choice;
    for(int i = 0; i < choices.length; i++){
        Integer j = i+1;
        System.out.println("\t\t" + j + ". " + choices[i]);
        choiceIdentifiers = choiceIdentifiers + j.toString();
    }
    System.out.print("Choice: ");
    while (!sc.hasNext("[" + choiceIdentifiers +"]")) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(""); 
        System.out.println("That's not an option! Please try again.");
        System.out.println(prompt);
        for(int i = 0; i < choices.length; i++){
            System.out.println("\t\t" + (i+1) + ". " + choices[i]);
        }
        System.out.print("Choice: ");
        sc.next();
    }
    choice = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
    sc.close();
    return choice - 1;
}
```

[Also here's a link to my github repo with the full program.](https://github.com/Ryan-M-White/HW4)

What could be happening in the showMenu function to crash the program and throw the NoSuchElementException?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're closing the `System.in` stream when you call `sc.close()`.

When you construct a new `Scanner` that uses the closed `System.in` stream and you call `next()` on it, you'll get this error.

To solve the problem, don't close the `System.in` (don't call `close()` on any `Scanner` that uses this stream) until you're done processing user input.

Here is a MCVE:

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        sc1.close();
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        sc2.next(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in Vechile.java show menu method

```
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(prompt);
        String choiceIdentifiers = "";
        int choice;
        for(int i = 0; i < choices.length; i++){
            Integer j = i+1;
            System.out.println("\t\t" + j + ". " + choices[i]);
            choiceIdentifiers = choiceIdentifiers + j.toString();
        }
```

so here after iterating on choices array you are concatinating choiceIdentifiers string that will become 12 after loop but you are expecting input from user as 1 or 2 for model type of vechile so if you will put 1 for model then

```
!sc.hasNext("[" + choiceIdentifiers +"]")
```

is not having 1 so it will throw no such element error , hope this will help you